# Person doesn’t or don’t

Tags: grammaticality

Which is grammatically correct, if a person doesn’t or don’t learn from something, then they’re doomed to repeat it.

Comment: Please explain why you think this noun would behave differently from other nouns. A car does. A rabbit does. A mother does. A house does. A teacher does. A person do?

Comment: It’s relatively the same

Comment: But I can’t help but question the way the sentence is constructed. Subject-Verb agreement. A singular subject requires a singular verb etc.

Comment: Yes, a singular subject requires a singular verb. Your sentence is constructed such that the subject is singular. So the verb must be plural?

Comment: Since does is used with singular noun (s), then a person doesn’t would be grammatically correct.